# Why is that only messageSource is allowed as bean id for ResourceBundleMessageSource?

Tags: java, spring

For Beans, usually we can customise the *id* attribute but for ResourceBundleMessageSource class, if we dont specify ***id*="messageSource"** then a exception is thrown.

```
<bean id="myMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="message" />
</bean>
```

It throws the Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException:
```

for code

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml").getMessage("code");
```

Comment: Good question, that had me pulling my hair for a few hours !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer - because that's the way they designed it.

As described in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource):

> When an `ApplicationContext` is loaded, it automatically searches for a `MessageSource` bean defined in the context. **The bean must have the name `messageSource`.** If such a bean is found, all calls to the preceding methods are delegated to the message source.... If the `ApplicationContext` cannot find any source for messages, an empty `DelegatingMessageSource` is instantiated in order to be able to accept calls to the methods defined above.

This is just a hard-coded value that is searched for. If you don't supply a bean with that name, you'll end up with a [`DelegatingMessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/DelegatingMessageSource.html) instance that won't resolve any of your messages, giving you a `NoSuchMessageException`.

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource):

> When an ApplicationContext is loaded, it automatically searches for a MessageSource bean defined in the context. The bean must have the name messageSource. If such a bean is found, all calls to the preceding methods are delegated to the message source. If no message source is found, the ApplicationContext attempts to find a parent containing a bean with the same name. If it does, it uses that bean as the MessageSource. If the ApplicationContext cannot find any source for messages, an empty DelegatingMessageSource is instantiated in order to be able to accept calls to the methods defined above.