# Why is getMessage() of ApplicationContext not reading .properties file: Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm going through Spring's **MessageSource** online tutorials. I'm not able to figure where I went wrong in this small piece of code. 

Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Shape shape = (Shape) context.getBean("circle"); 

        shape.draw(); 

        System.out.println(context.getMessage("greeting",null, "Default greeting", null));

    }
}
```

Configuration file, `spring.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="model" /> 

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="point1" class="model.Point">
        <property name="x" value="20 " />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

> mymessages.properties File:
>
> ```
> greeting=hello!
> ```

When I run the `main()` method, the following is the **Output**:

```
drawing circle with
Point (x = 20, y = 0)
Default greeting
```

**My question is**, why is the greeting `hello!` as mentioned in `mymessages.properties` file  is not getting printed ?  By the way, I have placed all the files in the correct directory only.

Comment: Where is your properties files? Have you tried with classpath:my messages?

Comment: This looks like directory structure problem even if you so much sure about doing it correctly. Please share your build configuration is. pom.xml if maven or the build system you are using like ant or gradle or maven.

Comment: place your **mymessages.properties** file under the **src folder** not in any **package**.

Comment: yes. It's in the `src` folder only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24486793/7004388) helped me to write an answer for my question.
In my Configuration file, `spring.xml`I didn't mention `id = messageSource` in `<bean>` element. The correct code is written below:

```
<bean id = "messageSource"
 class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basenames">
       <list>
          <value>mymessages</value>
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

> When an `ApplicationContext` is loaded, it automatically searches for
>   a MessageSource bean defined in the context. So, the bean must have
>   the name `messageSource`.